# See full input layout on bottom when opening virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity

In my overall `LinearLayout` I have an input area (also wrapped in a linear layout) which is at the very bottom of the layout. I want the user to see the full input area (not only the `EditText` element, but also the wrapping linear layout).

For this I have added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to my AndroidManifest file. Which works great, but I do not see the whole linear layout at the bottom, it's half-way truncated. I do see the `EditText` at least half, so that the blinking cursor is fully visible.

What can I do so that I see the whole bottom layout?

Comment: Please provide a bit more details, like the structure of the layout, orientation, etc

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard will be moved/aligned with the item that is focused (your input EditText element). Make sure that height of your EditText is the same as your wrapping LinearLayout. If you use LinearLayout to add some padding you can switch to EditText that have margin on top/bottom instead.